# Google Chrome Plugin - How to fetch and evaluate programmatically a js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-security-policy

The goal is to download a js from an external server and use functions and objects defined in that file.

My code:

```
const loadScript = (FILE_URL, async = true, type = "text/javascript") => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
          const scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
          scriptEle.type = type;
          scriptEle.async = async;
          scriptEle.src =FILE_URL;

          scriptEle.addEventListener("load", (ev) => {
              resolve({ status: true });
          });

          scriptEle.addEventListener("error", (ev) => {
              reject({
                  status: false,
                  message: `Failed to load the script ${FILE_URL}`
              });
          });

          document.body.appendChild(scriptEle);
      } catch (error) {
          reject(error);
      }
  });

loadScript("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/test.js")
      .then( data  => {
          console.log("Script loaded successfully", data);
      })
      .catch( err => {
          console.error(err);
      });
    };
```

Error:
Refused to load the script 'xxxxxxxx' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

I tried to play with the manifest but without success.
Can anyone provide me with an example?

Comment: Is this happening on a specific site, or is your extension for multiple sites? there's some decent documentation for extension CSP over on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_Security_Policy) - it may apply to Chrome (they are fairly compatible) - you could look for similar documentation over on google - but in general, googles documentation for chrome web extensions is 

Comment: ManifestV3 forbids external code.

Comment: If you load the script source in a iframe inside a sandbox page you should not have any problem.